# Segmentation violation in Singularity Container with matlab

Tags: matlab, segmentation-fault, singularity-container

For deployment on a cluster i am packaging a academic software called leverjs inside a Singularity container. It comes with prebuild Matlab packages that get run from the software. I have installed the Matlab runtime R2017b, leverjs and all dependencies inside the container via a recipe file.

Leverjs converts and analyses Image files that are on the home path, which is automatically bound to the Singularity container.

But while running leverjs from the container and calling the precompiled matlab code, Matlab crashes with a segmentation violation. 
Leverjs itself runs on electron.
How can Matlab cause a segfault if all the dependencies and the Matlab runtime  are in the container?

The Recipe file:
    Bootstrap: docker
    From: ubuntu

```
%setup
  hostname -f > $SINGULARITY_ROOTFS/etc/build_host

  # or  #wget http://ssd.mathworks.com/supportfiles/downloads/R2017b/deployment_files/R2017b/installers/glnxa64/MCR_R2017b_glnxa64_installer.zip and unzip to location
    #mkdir matlab
    #unzip MCR_R2017b_glnxa64_installer.zip -d matlab

  cp -R /home/cewa/Downloads/matlab ${SINGULARITY_ROOTFS}/matlab

%post
    apt-get update 
apt-get -y upgrade
apt-get -y install git \
nodejs \
npm \
wget \
libgtk-3-dev \
libxss1 \
libgconf2-4 \
libnss3 \
libasound2-dev

# install git lfs
wget https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/releases/download/v2.5.2/git-lfs-linux-amd64-v2.5.2.tar.gz
mkdir git-lfs
tar -C git-lfs -xf git-lfs-linux-amd64-v2.5.2.tar.gz
cd git-lfs
./install.sh
git lfs install

#install matlab dependency
cd ..
cd matlab
./install -mode silent -agreeToLicense yes

mkdir -p /opt/local
cd /opt/local
git clone --depth=1 https://git-bioimage.coe.drexel.edu/opensource/leverjs.git
git clone --depth=1 https://git-bioimage.coe.drexel.edu/opensource/leverUtilities.git
cd leverjs
npm update
npm run postinstall
chmod +x -R prebuilt/

## change path in CmdLoop.js to correct matlab path
cd leverjs
sed -i 's@/usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/@/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v93@' CmdLoop.js


##add cleanup
echo $PWD
cd /
echo $PWD
rm -rf git-lfs-linux-amd64-v2.5.2.tar.gz
rm -rf git-lfs
rm -rf matlab
apt clean
apt autoclean
apt autoremove

%runscript
cd /opt/local/leverjs
npm start

%apprun leverjs
cd /opt/local/leverjs
exec npm start


%apprun leverjs-server
exec node server.js --port=3000 "$@"
```

The matlab crash dump:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
       Segmentation violation detected at Thu Sep 20 15:29:40 2018
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration:
  Crash Decoding      : Disabled - No sandbox or build area path
  Crash Mode          : continue (default)
  Default Encoding    : US-ASCII
  GNU C Library       : 2.27 stable
  Host Name           : X8DA3
  MATLAB Architecture : glnxa64
  MATLAB Root         : /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v93
  MATLAB Version      : 9.3.0.713579 (R2017b)
  Operating System    : Linux 4.15.0-34-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 27 15:21:48 UTC 2018 x86_64
  Processor ID        : x86 Family 6 Model 26 Stepping 5, GenuineIntel

Fault Count: 1


Abnormal termination:
Segmentation violation

Register State (from fault):
  RAX = 0000000000000000  RBX = 00007ffc5c5a6a30
  RCX = 0000000000000000  RDX = 0000000000000001
  RSP = 00007ffc5c5a6990  RBP = 00007ffc5c5a69b0
  RSI = 00000000000000d8  RDI = 00007ffc5c5a6a48

   R8 = 00007ffc5c5a6bf0   R9 = 0000000000000001
  R10 = 0000000000000004  R11 = 00007fdcbf45c070
  R12 = 0000000000000001  R13 = 0000000003905600
  R14 = 00007ffc5c5a6a48  R15 = 00007ffc5c5a6a30

  RIP = 00007fdcb6e64c9e  EFL = 0000000000010206

       CS = 0033   FS = 0000   GS = 0000

    Stack Trace (from fault):
    [  0] 0x00007fdcb6e64c9e                 bin/glnxa64/libmwfoundation_usm.so+00056478 _ZN10foundation3usm10management10thisthread16ContextActivatorC1INS0_5scope3MvmEEERNS1_7ContextIT_EE+00000014
    [  1] 0x00007fdcb5795c36                            bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00457782
    [  2] 0x00007fdcb57cc0df                            bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00680159 _ZN11mcrInstance27feval_on_interpreter_threadEPKciPP11mxArray_tagiS4_+00000063
    [  3] 0x00007fdcb57d0051                            bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00696401 _ZN11mcrInstance18CallMATLABFunctionEPKciPP11mxArray_tagiS4_PNSt15__exception_ptr13exception_ptrE+00000129
    [  4] 0x00007fdcb57d0293                            bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00696979 _ZN11mcrInstance10EvalStringERKSbIDsSt11cha
7b5788                            bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00587656
    [ 20] 0x00007fdcb57b5a93                            bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00588435 _Z12mcr_run_mainRKN5boost9function0IiEEbb+00000243
    [ 21] 0x00007fdca3b135a8                       bin/glnxa64/libmwMVMLocal.so+00427432
    [ 22] 0x00007fdcb546e38d                            bin/glnxa64/libmwmvm.so+02507661
    [ 23] 0x00007fdcb5a926bd                        bin/glnxa64/libmwmclbase.so+00386749 mclRunMain+00000989
    [ 24] 0x00007fdca478bf02                         bin/glnxa64/libmwmclmcr.so+02191106 mclStandaloneGenericMain+00001074
    [ 25] 0x00007fdcbff84bd2                   bin/glnxa64/libmwlaunchermain.so+00048082
    [ 26] 0x0000000000408b06           /opt/local/leverjs/prebuilt/matlabPollDB+00035590
    [ 27] 0x00007fdcbf3e6b97                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+00138135 __libc_start_main+00000231
    [ 28] 0x0000000000404544           /opt/local/leverjs/prebuilt/matlabPollDB+00017732
    [ 29] 0x0000000000000000                                   <unknown-module>+00000000


    If this problem is reproducible, please submit a Service Request via:
        http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/

    A technical support engineer might contact you with further information.

    Thank you for your help.
```

I am hoping that this is not too off topic.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

leverjs is a software for visualization, 
you need to run singularity with OpenGL library support. add **--nv** option

for **%runscript** section

```
$ singularity run --nv --nv  image_test.simg
```

for **%apprun**

```
$ singularity run --nv --app leverjs-server image_test.simg [args]

$ singularity run --nv --app leverjs image_test.simg
```

Now, if you have problems with this technique, you can do bootstrap from a docker image containing [GL standard libraries no vendor](https://hub.docker.com/r/nvidia/opengl/) and add it to the option --nv

try this first, if the problem is still not solved, the problem is no longer slight to containers with Singularity, you should give more detail of what commands you use to run the container.

also this line from your crash dump

> Crash Decoding      : Disabled - No sandbox or build area path

***says that Matlab can not find the source files.***

Comment: Thank you. It was a library problem!